# How can I make my old wallet.dat work in a newer client?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, wallet.dat

Im having trouble with my wallet.dat file in the old bitcoin qt client the blockchain won't update because the computer is old and outdated so I'm unable to send the bitcoins that I have in the wallet to another address, so I downloaded bitcoin core onto my other computer and copied the wallet.dat file and replaced it and then in command prompt I rescanned and still nothing, could really use some help if anyone has any idea

Comment: when you say "still nothing", what do you mean?  no balance?  no transactions?  be clear, please!

Comment: Still no balance

Comment: On the old client it said 0.6 btc until I removed the wallet.dat file

Comment: So pretty much I need to import my new wallet.dat file into the new bitcoin core wallet

Comment: Try to dumpprivkey and import those private keys to electrum.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what dumpprivkeys means could you please explain the process to me, and thank you for helping

Comment: It should be possible to do a progressive upgrade and have Bitcoin Core upgrade the wallet file. It is not always possible to go directly from an old version to the newest version. If you were on v0.7.0 then install v0.8.0 (official downloads only!) and let it upgrade your wallet file automatically when you run it. Then install v0.9.0 and do it again, etc until you are on the current version.  I do not know what versions it is possible to skip but if you do them all it will not be wrong. Make sure you keep a good backup copy of your original wallet file.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to export the private key of your old wallet in the old QT client, and import it into the wallet in your new QT client. The steps to do this are:

Exporting the private key of your old wallet, containg the funds. To do this, in your old QT client, click `Help` > `Debug window` and go to `Console`
There, you can use the command [`dumpprivkey`](https://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api/dumpprivkey) command to export your private key. KEEP THIS SAFE, anyone with access to this key can do whatever they want with your wallet.

Now we import the private key into the new wallet and up-to-date QT client. To do this, repeat the previous steps: click `Help` > `Debug window`, and go to `Console` again. Then use the `importprivkey "KEYHERE"` command, where `KEYHERE` stands for the private key you exported.

The client will then scan the blockchain and, if it finds transactions pertaining to your old address/wallet, it will replay them, and you should dispose of your old funds.